# MySQL time format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
create table test
(
starttime time not null ;
endtime time not null
);
```

i want to enter time in this format
for example : 9:00 AM or 6:10 PM
this command gives me error

insert into test
(starttime ,endtime  )
values
('9:00 AM','6:10 PM');

Any Suggestion, thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean for the time to omit the date?  A "time" entry is a date and a time.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Comment: @wallyk That's  my initial reaction too; then [this showed up](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html). **edit** ...and Charles beat me to it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into test (starttime ,endtime ) 
values (str_to_date('9:00 AM','%l:%i %p'),str_to_date('6:10 PM','%l:%i %p'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either format your values as proper MySQL Time values:

```
insert into test (starttime ,endtime ) values ('09:00:00','18:10:00');
```

Or you can keep the format you have, in which case you need to convert those strings to valid MySQL Time values:

```
insert into test (starttime ,endtime ) 
values (str_to_date('9:00 AM','%l:%i %p'),str_to_date('6:10 PM','%l:%i %p'));
```